# c4458 warning - how to find which variable is used

Tags: c++

I need to port an old project to the latest visual studio but it has some very awful code in it that I don't know how to resolve.

if have this function:

```
void CBuffer::AddData( LPBYTE lpData, u_long uDataSize, u_long &uRemnant )
{
    int cb;
    LPBYTE ptr  = GetWritableBuffer( (int *)&cb );

    cb  = ( cb < uRemnant? cb: uRemnant );
    ASSERT( ptr + cb <= m_lpBufMax );
    memcpy( (void*)ptr, &lpData[uDataSize - uRemnant], cb );
    m_pTail = ptr + cb;
    uRemnant    -= cb;
}
```

which prompts

```
buffer.cpp(90): warning C4458: declaration of 'cb' hides class member
```

here int cb overwrite u_long cb defined by the class CBuffer.

Is there a way to tell which cb should be used after this?

```
LPBYTE ptr  = GetWritableBuffer( (int *)&cb );
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? When asking questions about build errors, please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question body, without modifications. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: yup i made a mistake in the title. It should be c4458 warning not error. edit: corrected

Comment: You're looking for `this->cb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables always shadow class member variables or global variables. So, in this method, always the local variable `int cb` is used.

Comment: was it the same in older version of visual studio ? this code was made using vs2003

Comment: @Harlockin yes is was certainly the same, but maybe vs2003 simply didn't show the warning.

Comment: This is defined in the C standard already (of course not for class member variables, but regarding to variables with same names in nested scopes) and was adopted by the C++ standard, so, yes, it must have been the same in older versions of Visual Studio.